# AngularJS compile html with directive and get output as string?

Tags: angularjs, templates, compilation, interpolation

Is there a way from an AngularJS controller or service to "compile/interpolate/whatever" a small html template which comes with a directive, and get the very final HTML output as a string?

More in details, let's say my template is like this:
`var html = '<span my-directive="myVariable"></span>'`, and my-directive is adding additional html while manipulating myVariable.

Now, I would like to compile that html `$compile(html)({myVariable: myVariable})` (not sure if it is the right way) and finally having a full html as a string as final result:

```html
<span my-directive="myVariable">
 <span>additional content added by my amazing directive while manipulating myVariable</span>
</span>
```

Any idea how to achieve this? Any advise is highly appreciated.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, **you can compile** HTML with directive (and also provide parameters/variables to that directive) and **finally get the rusult as a String**

Firstly, let's take a look [$compile documentation (Usage section)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#usage)

We can see there that $compile argument is

> Element or HTML string to compile into a template function.

in your case it is `var html`

and the returned value is

> a link function which is used to bind template (a DOM element/tree) to a scope

$compile is returning a **function that require scope as an argument**

scope is an special object so your `{myVariable: myVariable}` is not valid, if you want to pass variable to compilation, you have to assign this variable to your current scope `scope.myVariable = myVariable` and this scope has to be provided as an argument to link function `$compile(html)(scope)`

Now we must check what is returned by link function:

> Calling the linking function returns the element of the template

voila! - we have `Element Object` so we can get its `outerHTML` property and assign it to a variable

In [Pradeep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6537530/pradeep) [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4iYT8WPi1XWEJKrZzXBi?p=preview) you can change

```
var str = '<div my-directive>Hello world</div>'
var com = $compile(str)(scope);
element.append(com);
```

to

```
var str = '<div my-directive>Hello world</div>'
var com = $compile(str)(scope);
console.log('outerHTML',com[0].outerHTML);
element.append(com[0].outerHTML);
```

to watch results in console :)

NOTE: directive compiled in Plunker is not parametrized by any variable but you can change it of course (just remember that all variables used in compiled directive template have to be assigned to scope you compile with)

Answer (score 1):

`$compile` compiles an HTML string or DOM into a template and produces a template function, which can then be used to link `scope` and the template together.

If your requirement is to append a compiled directive into another directive you can do it inside `link` function.

```
var str = '<div my-directive>Hello world</div>'
var com = $compile(str)(scope);
element.append(com);
```

You can use $compile as shown in the above code inside link function.

Example provided at [Plnkr Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/4iYT8WPi1XWEJKrZzXBi?p=preview).

Comment: This is not exactly what I need. I would need more the final result in a string (final complete html with directive executed). I am not going to append it to a don element but rather injecting it in a translate-value of $translate service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $sce for that:

```
$scope.variable = $sce.trustAsHtml(yourHtmlString);
```

And then in your html you need to use:

```
<div ng-bind-html="variable"></div>
```